# MapReduce Hadoop Runtime String Exception

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying my hands on MapReduce program in Hadoop 2.6 using JAVA code. I tried to refer to other posts on Stack Overflow but failed to debug my code.

First let me describe the type of records : 
subId=00001111911128052627towerid=11232w34532543456345623453456984756894756bytes=122112212212212218.4621702216543667E17
subId=00001111911128052639towerid=11232w34532543456345623453456984756894756bytes=122112212212212219.6726312167218586E17
subId=00001111911128052615towerid=11232w34532543456345623453456984756894756bytes=122112212212212216.9431647633139046E17
subId=00001111911128052615towerid=11232w34532543456345623453456984756894756bytes=122112212212212214.7836041833447418E17

Now the Mapper Class: AircelMapper.class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.Long;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
public class AircelMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text, LongWritable>
{

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {

        String acquire=value.toString();
        String st=acquire.substring(81, 84);

        LongWritable bytes=new LongWritable(Long.parseLong(st));
        context.write(new Text(acquire.substring(6, 26)), bytes);
    }
}
```

Now the Driver Class: AircelDriver.class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class AircelDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException
    {
        if(args.length<2)
        {   System.out.println(" type ip and op file correctly");
            System.exit(-1);
        }


        Job job = Job.getInstance();

        job.setJobName(" @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@       MY FIRST PROGRAM        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");


        job.setJarByClass(AircelDriver.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setMapperClass(AircelMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(AircelReducer.class);
        job.submit();
        job.waitForCompletion(true);

    }
}
```

I am not posting the Reducer class since the problem is in mapper code during runtime. The output of the Hadoop runtime is as follows (which is essentially an indication of job failure):

```
    16/12/18 04:11:00 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1618565735_0001_m_000000_0
16/12/18 04:11:01 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
16/12/18 04:11:01 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
16/12/18 04:11:01 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/practice/Data_File.txt:0+1198702
16/12/18 04:11:01 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
16/12/18 04:11:01 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
16/12/18 04:11:01 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
16/12/18 04:11:01 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
16/12/18 04:11:01 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
16/12/18 04:11:01 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
16/12/18 04:11:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1618565735_0001 running in uber mode : false
16/12/18 04:11:01 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/12/18 04:11:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
16/12/18 04:11:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output
16/12/18 04:11:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 290000; bufvoid = 104857600
16/12/18 04:11:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 26174400(104697600); length = 39997/6553600
16/12/18 04:11:03 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
16/12/18 04:11:03 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
16/12/18 04:11:03 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1618565735_0001
****java.lang.Exception: **java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 84******
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 84
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
    at AircelMapper.map(AircelMapper.java:13)
    at AircelMapper.map(AircelMapper.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Fut
```

Why it is giving String Index out of bounds exception? Does String class have internally a limit on the size of the string? I do not understand what is problem on line 13-15 in the Mapper class.

Comment: try `acquire.substring(81, 84-1);` index starts from 0 and goes `string.length()-1`

Comment: but if you look at the each record length it crosses 110, so if the program is taking the entire line as string, trying to access 84 should not give error, right ? why is it limiting the string size ?

Comment: simply try to print the length of you string in code because error says `String index out of range: 84` mean string is not enough long

Comment: I tried another program (not the same hadoop program)where I supplied a record and it correctly printed out the length as 119.

Comment: i tried to run the job by inserting the print statement to print the record length, it printed n entries( as many am there are in the source file) to display the length of the String, and after it printed n entries it again gave the above error. So basically it is basically printing lengths of all recoed AND THEN ONLY it is starting to extract pairs from it. ISN'T THIS WEIRD ? MAPPER CODE EXECUTES FOR EVERY RECORD ONE AFTER THE OTHER, RIGHT? OR DOES IT EXECUTE FOR ALL THE FILE AT ONCE ? PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 0):

IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

public StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(int index)
Constructs a new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException class with an argument indicating the **illegal index**. - 84 (in your case)

public StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(String s)
Constructs a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException with the **specified detail message**. - array out of range (in your case)

Check your input at index 84.

Comment: Sir I know what that Exception means, but as I have already commented, at runtime as tried by me, the mapping phase is printing the length of all the input records then starting to process, which is actually weird, because  the mapreduce framework makes the Mapper class work on every input Record, which is not happening in my case. I mean what is this, some weird bug. Could you please ask your colleagues to help me out here.